# What time zone is the Facebook Ads Insights API's date_start and date_stop sent in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Facebook's Ads Insights API returns `date_start` and `date_stop` but since they're date objects I can't tell what time zone was used to demarcate the dates. Is it using Facebook's API timezone which they've mentioned to be PT (UTC -8) or is it according to the AdAccount's time zone as I've found mentions of the account's time zone in the Ads Insights API documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Facebook API does not have the ability to specify a time zone. The time zone is defined at the advertising account level in the settings. Api adopts and returns a date range based on these settings.

Answer (score 0):

The time zone used for the insights will be that of the advertiser account set on account creation. You can find out the ad account's time zone with the field [`AdAccount.timezone_id`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/ad-accounts/). There's a list of timezone IDs on [this docs page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/timezone-ids/v17.0).